# A bit of clarification on how EBOs work (Element array buffers)

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I understand that a EBO can be bound to a VAO, unlike the other OpenGL buffer objects. I also know that if no VAO is bound at the time of binding the EBO, the EBO is bound to the OpenGL context or the global state. My question is when you bind a EBO to a VAO, then unbind the VAO, and bind the EBO again, is the EBO bound to the VAO, the global state, or both? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I understand that a EBO can be bound to a VAO, unlike the other OpenGL buffer objects.

First, some terminology.

In OpenGL, you do not bind an object to another object. You *attach* one object to another. "Bind" is only used when putting the object in the context.

When you call `glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,...)`, you are *attaching* the buffer to the current VAO. Yes, I know the function says "bind", and it behaves a lot like a regular context binding point, but OpenGL functions say a lot of stupid things. There's a reason why the DSA-equivalent is called `glVertexArrayElementBuffer`, with no "bind" in sight.

> I also know that if no VAO is bound at the time of binding the EBO, the EBO is bound to the OpenGL context or the global state.

This is half true. In a compatibility context, VAO 0 is a default VAO object. That is, `glBindVertexArray(0)` is a valid object. So if you call `glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,...)` with VAO object 0 bound, you are attaching the buffer to VAO 0.

In a core context, there is no VAO 0. Therefore, `glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ...)` will result in a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error.

> My question is when you bind a EBO to a VAO, then unbind the VAO, and bind the EBO again, is the EBO bound to the VAO, the global state, or both?

A buffer can be attached to any number of VAOs. So the fact that you attach a buffer to VAO 0 will not change the fact that it is attached to some other VAO.

Answer (score 1):

From OpenGL specifications:

> A buffer object is created by binding a name returned by GenBuffers to
>   a buffer target. The binding is effected by calling void [gl]BindBuffer(
>   enum target, uint buffer ); target must be one of the targets listed
>   in table...

Bindind a buffer is describing how it will be used. For example, using *target* =`GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` you *bind* the buffer as an EBO.

> DrawElements, DrawRangeElements, and DrawElementsInstanced source
>   their indices from the buffer object whose name is bound to [GL_]ELEMENT_
>   ARRAY_BUFFER,

So, the currently bound [elements] buffer is used.

VAO's store the binding. When you "active" again the VAO by `glBindVertexArray` the EBO gets bound again "automagically".

Comment: I'm aware how I bind the buffer to GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER and it "becomes an EBO". I'm also aware that if a VAO is bound at the time of binding the 'glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferID)' that the binding is reflected in the VAOs state.I'm also aware that when I bind the EBO to a VAO, then unbind the VAO, the EBO will also be unbound. My question is if a EBO is bound to a VAO, and the VAO is unbound, what will happen when I bind the same buffer using 'glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferID)'. Will the buffer be bound to the global state, the VAO, or both?

Comment: @pdid: "*I'm also aware that when I bind the EBO to a VAO, then unbind the VAO, the EBO will also be unbound.*" You're not really understanding that part. When you *attach* the buffer object to the VAO, it is attached *to the VAO*, not to the context.

Comment: In that case,what happens if I bind a buffer to the Element array buffer without a VAO being bound?

Comment: In that case what happens if I bind a buffer to GL_ELEMENT_BUFFER when no VAO is bound?

Comment: Try drawing without VAO but with an EBO bound after setting a core profile context (not compatibility profile). You'll see it.